# How to variables to cut command in unix for -f option

Tags: unix, command, cut

I need to parse a `sql` file and pull all the statements.

For example `sample.sql` is like this

```
alter table add column(c1 varchar(20));
alter table add column(c2 varchar2(10));
```

Now i want to write a script in the below manner.

```
#!/bin/ksh
for file in sample.sql
do
    echo $file
    no_of_statement=`grep ";" $file|wc -l`
    echo $no_of_statement
    iterator=1
    statement=""
    while [ $iterator -le $no_of_statement]
        do
            echo "Inside While Loop"
            statement=`cat $file`
            statement1=`echo $statement | cut -d";" -f "${iterator}"`
            echo $statement1
            iterator=$iterator+1
        done
done
```

Comment: Please *preview* your post carefully and use proper formatting.

Comment: Hi Martin,Sure..will do that..i'm actually new to this, used long back...

Comment: @user1749169: What are you trying to achieve here? Please paste your expected o/p?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change `[ $iterator -le $no_of_statement]` to `[ $iterator -le $no_of_statement ]`

and 
`iterator=$iterator+1` to `iterator=$(($iterator+1))`

It prints the queries:

```
sample.sql
2
Inside While Loop
alter table add column(c1 varchar(20))
Inside While Loop
alter table add column(c2 varchar2(10))
```